Open a windows program through a https link from the native firefox in bottles
I have installed a windows program through bottles. To get access to the server inside the program, I have to open it trough a https link. If I click on the link, firefox asks, allow ... to open the ls3d link? I confirm and click on "choose an application" and choose the right application in the directory from bottles. But it doesnt open the program. How can I open the program in bottles with my native browser?
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Can you try the apt firefox instead of the snap firefox? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Thank you for the fast answer. The APT Version says when I click on the link. The address wasn’t understood. Problem landing page. The link should open the program I installed via bottles.

So, is there any difference between the apt and the snap versions or not?

Yes. The snap version asks me, If firefox should open the link and with which application. So I confirm and choose the right application. But the application does not start.

Is there any reason you're trying to use a windows program instead of a native equivalent that does the same job?

Yes. There is no native equivalent out there. If I use the program through a VM it works. But it is very slow. 3 FPS and the fans are running on high level. If I use the programm through wine, it runs very smooth. I just have to open the link, that opens the launcher.exe. How can I achieve that?
